# Laravel Remember_token is no longer being created by Laravel

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel

I just switched to a PostgreSQL Database from mysql. Right now I cannot create users because since I switched to PostgreSQL Laravel seems to no longer be generating a remember_token, and I receive this error:

`"SQLSTATE[23502]: Not null violation: 7 ERROR: null value in column "remember_token" violates not-null constraint DETAIL: Failing row contains (blah blah blah)"`

what has happened?

Comment: Did you make the field `nullable` in SchemaBuilder ? `$table->string('remember_token')->nullable()`.

Comment: no I did not, I did not know it was supposed to be nullable, I will try that

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the remember token needed to be nullable, thank you mohebifar